# addClass/removeClass and toggle

Tags: jquery

I have written toggle code below, I need "active" class should toggle when "Map / View" toggle. When I click on another link first should remove  and apply to clicked link.

[**Check Here**](https://jsfiddle.net/alpeshlahad/pe6oj4gL/4/)

**HTML:**

```
<div class="member-view-switch">
  <a href="#" class="toggle-button active">Tile</a>
  <a href="#" class="toggle-button">Map</a>
</div>

<div class="toggle-item target-tile-view">
  Tile View
</div>

<div class="toggle-item target-map-view">
  Map View
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.member-view-switch {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

a,
:hover,
:focus {
  color;
  #333333;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding-right: 15px;
}

.active {
  color: blue;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.toggle-item {
  border: 1px solid #333;
  padding: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
```

**jQuery:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  $(".target-map-view").css("display", "none");
  $(".toggle-button").click(function() {
    if ($(this).hasClass("active")) {
      $(".target-tile-view").show();
      $(".target-map-view").hide();
    } else {
      $(".target-tile-view").hide();
      $(".target-map-view").show();
    }
  });

});
```

Answer (score 1):

**Solution**

While clicking `Title` or `Map` you have to remove the class active from the navigation and ad that to current element.`$(this)` is used to get the current element.

```
$(".toggle-button").removeClass("active")
$(this).addClass("active")
```

---

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  $(".target-map-view").css("display", "none");
  $(".toggle-button").click(function() {
    $(".toggle-button").removeClass("active")    // Newly added
    $(this).addClass("active")     // Newly added
    if ($(this).hasClass("active")) {
      $(".target-tile-view").show();
      $(".target-map-view").hide();
    } else {
      $(".target-tile-view").hide();
      $(".target-map-view").show();
    }
  });

});
```

**[Working Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/Rino_Raj/pe6oj4gL/7/)**

Answer (score 1):

Just rewrite your code like below,

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var items = $(".toggle-item");
  items.filter(".target-map-view").hide();
  var buttons = $(".toggle-button").click(function() {
    buttons.removeClass("active").filter(this).addClass("active");
    items.hide().eq($(this).index()).show();
  });
});
```

This code will work for any number of tabs and contents.

### [DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/pe6oj4gL/8/)

Answer (score 0):

Try this : As you initially hiding map view button and div, you can easily use `toggle()` to show / hide map and tile view. And use `toggleClass("active")` to add remove active class.

And to avoid malfunctioning when user clicks same button continuosly, we can check if the clicked button was previously clicked or not.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var $clickedButton =  $(".toggle-button.active");
  $(".target-map-view").css("display", "none");
  $(".toggle-button").click(function() {
       //if previously clicked then return and do nothing
      if($clickedButton.is($(this)))
         return true;

      $clickedButton = $(this);
      $(".toggle-button").toggleClass("active");
      $(".target-tile-view").toggle();
      $(".target-map-view").toggle();

  });

});
```

**[JSFiddle Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/pe6oj4gL/13/)**

Comment: Continuously clicking on `map/title` tab would toggle the menu selection automatically.

Comment: @RajaprabhuAravindasamy, yeah I missed that , thanks. I have updated my asnwer.